# Cargo test doesn't find test

Tags: rust-cargo

I have the tests module outside my src folder and cargo test does not find the test functions inside tests/types/typed.rs

cargo clean did not solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

It seems that renaming types to my_types fixed the problem.